# Show that $(A')'⊆ A'$ is not always true.

Tags: general-topology

Asumme that $(S,T) $ is topology space and A is a subset of $S $ and $A'$ is set of limit pointso of set $A$ show that $(A')'⊆ A'$ is not always true.

I can't find a example to show that.

Comment: What about the empty set?

Comment: Following up on @Jeremy's comment, does $\subset$ mean $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$ to you?

Comment: I interpret $A \subset S$ as a subset of $S$ that is not the whole $S$, i.e. $A \subseteq S \wedge A \neq S$

Comment: @HenningMakholm edited thanks

Comment: It is always true in metric spaces

Comment: It's true in $T_1$ spaces, so look at indiscrete, included and excluded topology etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m going to assume that your definition of *limit point* is that $x\in A'$ if and only if each open nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $A\setminus\{x\}$. Let $X=\{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology $\{\varnothing,X\}$, and let $A=\{0\}$. Then $A'=\{1\}$, and $(A')'=\{0\}$.

If $X$ is a $T_1$-space, we always have $(A')'\subseteq A'$. To see this, suppose that $x\in(A')'$, and let $U$ be any open nbhd of $x$. Then $U\cap(A'\setminus\{x\})\ne\varnothing$, so there is a $y\in U\cap(A'\setminus\{x\})=(U\setminus\{x\})\cap A'$. $X$ is $T_1$, so $\{x\}$ is a closed set, and $U\setminus\{x\}$ is therefore an open nbhd of $y$. Finally, $y\in A'$, so

$$U\cap(A\setminus\{x\})=(U\setminus\{x\})\cap A\ne\varnothing\;.$$

$U$ was an arbitrary open nbhd of $x$, so this shows that $x\in A'$ and hence that $(A')'\subseteq A'$.

Comment: @mahdi: You’re welcome.